# How can I setup Jest with a transpiler so that I can have automatically mocked DOM and canvas?

Tags: dom, jestjs, html5-canvas, babeljs, babel-jest

I have a small, browser-based game that I'm trying to get Jest up and running with.

My goal is to be able to write tests, and to have them run with Jest, and not to have any extra DOM- or browser API-related error messages.

As the game makes use of DOM and canvas, I need a solution where I can either mock those manually, or have Jest take care of it for me. At a minimum, I'd like to verify that the 'data model' and my logic is sane.

I'm also making use of ES6 modules.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Tried running jest:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /home/dingo/code/game-sscce/game.spec.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { Game } from './game';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I understood here that I can experimentally enable ES module support, or use a transpiler to output ES5 that Jest can recognize and run.

So my options are:

- Enable experimental ES module support
- Transpile using Babel
- Transpile using Parcel
- Transpile using Webpack

I decided to try Babel and looked here for instructions: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel

2. I created a babel.config.js file in the root directory.

After installing babel and creating a config file, here's an SSCCE:

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env'
        ]
    ],
};
```

**game.js**

```
export class Game {
  constructor() {
    document.getElementById('gameCanvas').width = 600;
  }
}

new Game();
```

**game.spec.js**

```
import { Game } from './game';

test('instantiates Game', () => {
  expect(new Game()).toBeDefined();
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="module" src="game.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gameContainer">
        <canvas id="gameCanvas" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "game-sscce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  }
}
```

Now when I try running Jest again, I get:

```
 FAIL  ./game.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null

      1 | export class Game {
      2 |   constructor() {
    > 3 |     document.getElementById('gameCanvas').width = 600;
        |     ^
      4 |   }
      5 | }
      6 |

      at new Game (game.js:3:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (game.js:7:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (game.spec.js:1:1)
```

...and now, I'm not sure what to do. If document is not being recognized, then I suspect Jest is not making use of jsdom properly. Am I supposed to configure anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigation:

[Jest runs with jsdom by default](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string).

`document` actually exists:

[image]

However, since it's mocked, `getElementById()` just returns `null`.

In this situation, it's not possible to return an existing canvas defined in the HTML document. Rather, one can create the canvas programmatically:

**game.js**

```
export class Game {
  constructor() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'gameCanvas');
    document.getElementById('gameContainer').append(canvas);

    canvas.width = 600;
  }
}

new Game();
```

`getElementById()` will, however, still return `null`, so this call must be mocked:

**game.spec.js**

```
import { Game } from './game';

test('instantiates Game', () => {
  jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').mockReturnValue({})
  expect(new Game()).toBeDefined();
});
```

The test still fails to run:

```
 FAIL  ./game.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

      3 |     const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      4 |     canvas.setAttribute('id', 'gameCanvas');
    > 5 |     document.getElementById('gameContainer').append(canvas);
        |     ^
      6 |
      7 |     canvas.width = 600;
      8 |

      at new Game (game.js:5:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (game.js:16:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (game.spec.js:1:1)
```

This is because `Game` is instantiating itself as soon as Jest imports it due to the `new Game()` call on the last line. Once rid of that:

**game.js**

```
export class Game {
  constructor() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'gameCanvas');
    document.getElementById('gameContainer').append(canvas);

    canvas.width = 600;
  }
}
```

We get:

```
 FAIL  ./game.spec.js
  ✕ instantiates Game (7 ms)

  ● instantiates Game

    TypeError: document.getElementById(...).append is not a function

      3 |     const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      4 |     canvas.setAttribute('id', 'gameCanvas');
    > 5 |     document.getElementById('gameContainer').append(canvas);
        |                                              ^
      6 |
      7 |     canvas.width = 600;
      8 |

      at new Game (game.js:5:46)
      at Object.<anonymous> (game.spec.js:5:10)
```

One step closer, but the `append()` call must also be mocked out:

**game.spec.js**

```
import { Game } from './game';

test('instantiates Game', () => {
  jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').mockReturnValue({
    append: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({})
  });
  expect(new Game()).toBeDefined();
});
```

...and now the test passes:

```
 PASS  ./game.spec.js
  ✓ instantiates Game (9 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
```

It's interesting that jsdom returns an HTMLCanvasElement when created programmatically and mocked:

[image]

However, it can't really be used for anything:

**game.js**

```
export class Game {
  constructor() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'gameCanvas');

    document.getElementById('gameContainer').append(canvas);

    canvas.width = 600;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

As shown by the failing test:

```
 FAIL  ./game.spec.js
  ✕ instantiates Game (43 ms)

  ● instantiates Game

    TypeError: Cannot set property 'fillStyle' of null

      10 |     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      11 |
    > 12 |     ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
         |     ^
      13 |     ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
      14 |
      15 |     ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)';

      at new Game (game.js:12:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (game.spec.js:7:10)

  console.error
    Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package)
        at module.exports (/home/dingo/code/game-sscce/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:9:17)
        at HTMLCanvasElementImpl.getContext (/home/dingo/code/game-sscce/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLCanvasElement-impl.js:42:5)
        at HTMLCanvasElement.getContext (/home/dingo/code/game-sscce/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/HTMLCanvasElement.js:130:58)
        at new Game (/home/dingo/code/game-sscce/game.js:10:22)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dingo/code/game-sscce/game.spec.js:7:10)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/home/dingo/code/game-sscce/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:106:37)
        at /home/dingo/code/game-sscce/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/home/dingo/code/game-sscce/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
        at /home/dingo/code/game-sscce/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41 undefined

       8 |     canvas.width = 600;
       9 |
    > 10 |     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         |                      ^
      11 |
      12 |     ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
      13 |     ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
```

To be able to test further, either of the following two conditions must be fulfilled:

- [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) has to be installed as a peer dependency of jsdom,
- [jest-canvas-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-canvas-mock) has to be installed.